# Displaying ASCII characters from an array on a LCD with ATmega32

Tags: c, gcc, avr, avr-gcc, atmel

I've got an LCD, connected to an Atmega32, working with single characters using this function:

```
void send_char(uint8_t c){
    PORTD = c; // set the output pins to the ascii value of the char
    PORTB |= 0x05;
    _delay_us(1);
    PORTB &= 0xfa;
    _delay_us(60);
    PORTD = 0x00;
    update_cursor();
}
```

I can call this with a character as an argument: `send_char('a');` and it works.

Then I tried wrapping a send_string function around it:

```
void send_string(const char * msg){
    while (*msg != '\0'){
        send_char(*msg++);
    }
}
```

This just puts gibberish on my LCD indicating that the ASCII value has been far off. And when I try passing an empty string (`send_string("")`) a minimum of three gibberish characters get displayed on the LCD.

Comment: Sending with the empty string should be a do-nothing, since `*msg == '\0'`. Is there code being executed after this that might garble your display? Is the display being initialized properly?

Comment: the display seems to be initialized correctly since i can send any number of chars using send_char() and everything is fine and nothing else gets send to the display except an update of the cursor position from send_char.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, it seems that you are using the avr-gcc compiler. When making questions for embedded devices, you always need to say which compiler you are using.

I will now try to help you understand what is wrong with your code and why your solution works. The function you have defined:

```
void send_string(const char * msg);
```

expects a string pointer in RAM. It doesn't matter that you have used the `const` keyword, the compiler still expects the string to be in RAM. So if you have a string in ROM:

```
const char msg[] PROGMEM = "Test";
```

and you try to pass it in your function:

```
send_string(msg);
```

it just passes an invalid address to it and thus gibberish are displayed. If instead you copy it first to RAM, as you did in your solution, it works fine:

```
char buf[strlen(msg)];
strcpy_P(buf,msg);
send_string(buf);
```

If you want to define a function that will directly read a ROM string, you can do it like this:

```
void send_string_P(const char *data)
{
    while (pgm_read_byte(data) != 0x00)
        send_char(pgm_read_byte(data++));
}
```

Notice the `_P` suffix. This is the general convention used to distinct functions that operate on ROM from the ones that operate on RAM.

All these and more are nicely explained [here](http://www.avrfreaks.net/index.php?name=PNphpBB2&file=viewtopic&t=38003). I also suggest that you try the *[AVR Freaks](http://www.avrfreaks.net/)* forum for these kind of questions. People there will be certainly more experienced in these issues than Stack Overflow users and are always happy to help.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything obviously wrong with your code (not that I know how to talk to an Atmega32).  Try running it under a debugger and print `c` on every invocation to `send_char`, or just put `printf("%d\n", (int)c);` as the first line to `send_char`.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

void send_char(uint8_t c)
{
    printf("%c", c);
}

void send_string(const char * msg)
{
    while (*msg != '\0')
    {
        send_char(*msg++);
    }
}

int main()
{
    send_string("Stackoverflow!");

    return 0;
}
```

In your code, insert  `sleep(1);` after the `send_char()` call and see if it changes the behavior you are observing.

Answer (score 1):

This works on my Atmel controller (although I don't know why):

First one has to add the literal to the ROM via PROGMEM from `<avr/pgmspace.h>`:

```
const char msg[] PROGMEM = "Test";
```

Then copy the literal to a buffer in the controller's RAM:

```
char buf[strlen(msg)];
strcpy_P(buf,msg);
```

Now `send_string(msg)` can be used as expected..

Comment: you did not show us how msg was defined beforehand, how you call send_string()

Comment: @limubs: like i wrote in the question i was calling send_string(""). and even with an empty string i would get garbled characters...

Comment: @caf: since it's the same as saying const char msg="Test" but the char array has to be in the ROM first in the Atmega32 this did not work.

Comment: @smeg4brains: `char buf[] = "Test"` will create `buf` in data space, just like `char buf[strlen(msg)];` does.

Comment: @smeg4brains: That looks like a bug - what does `char buf[1] = "";` do? What about `char buf[1] = { 0 };`?

Comment: @caf: `char buf[1]="";` produces the same garbled result but `char buf[2]={97,0}` does prints an 'a' on the lcd..

Comment: @smeg4brains: You should also be able to use `{'a', '\0'}` if `{97, 0}` works.  I would submit this as a compiler bug to the vendor - `char buf[2] = { 'a', '\0'};` and `char buf[2] = "a";` are supposed to be *exactly* the same.